# Number of elements in $\{z \in \Bbb{C}: z^{60} = -1, z^k \neq -1 \:\text{ for }\: 0 < k < 60\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

How many elements does the set $S = \{z \in \Bbb{C}: z^{60} = -1, z^k \neq -1 \:\text{ for }\: 0 < k < 60\}$ have?

If $z \in S$ then $z^{60}$ = $-1$ and hence $z^{120}$ = $1$.

How can I find any condition on $z$ from here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know $z=e^{\dfrac{in \pi}{60}}$ for some odd $n$.

Assume $\gcd(n, 60)=1$.  Then if $\frac{nk}{60}$ is an odd integer (as is required for $z^k=-1$ to hold), then we know $60 \mid nk$.  But since $n$ and $60$ are relatively prime, then $60 \mid k$, so in particular $k \geq 60$.  Thus, $\{ e^{\dfrac{in \pi}{60}} \mid \gcd (n, 60)=1 \} \subseteq S$.

Conversely, suppose $d \gt 1$ is a common factor of $n$ and $60$.  Then for some $a, b \in \Bbb Z, n=da$ and $60=db.$  Moreover, because $n$ is odd, $a$ must also be odd.  Thus, $z=e^{\dfrac{ia \pi}{b}}$ and $z^b=-1$ where $b \lt 60$.  Thus, $S=\{ e^{\dfrac{in \pi}{60}} \mid \gcd (n, 60)=1 \}$.

There are $16$ integers less than $60$ that are relatively prime to $60$, so $\vert S \vert = 16$.

Comment: How did you even get the first step?..I can see that $z = e^{i\theta}$ but why will $\theta$ will be of that form?

Comment: Because $z^{60}=-1=e^{in \pi}$ for some odd $n$.

Comment: $z^{60}$ is -1? for what $z$?

Comment: That's what you're solving for.  You're trying to figure out what $z$ has to be if $z^{60}=-1$.  You can see that $z$ must be of the form $e^{i \theta}$, so that boils down to solving for $\theta$.  Since $60 \theta = n \pi$ for some odd $n$, this means $\theta=\frac{n \pi}{60}$ for some odd $n$.

Comment: Oh okay..got it

Comment: Isn't $z^{60} = -1 = e^{\frac{in\pi}{60}}$ for all odd $n$?

Comment: For any particular $z, n$ can only take on $1$ value $\pmod {60}$.